# Render templates from complex MongoDB queries in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, handlebars.js

I apologize for the roughly-drafted question, but I'm not sure what the best practices are for using the combination of meteor, mongo, and handlebars.

I understand the point of making handlebars logic-less and, although I would have been more comfortable in Jade, I kept with handlebars for the native meteor support. However, I don't really know what the best way to assign data to a template might be.

This is especially in cases where I need to access multiple collections and access a document that is referenced by another document in another collection (by Id) or in cases where I need to use the index variable generally provided from a for loop. Preserving Meteor's auto-updating functionality seems to add a little bit more complexity to the matter.

I guess, *in the form of a question:*

**Should I be making my complex queries, joining them all into a single array of objects (so that all relative data is nested), adding an index variable to each, and making the array available for looping in the template?**

**-OR-**

**Should I be making each db query in each template's controller, then trying to break the data down to its simplest form and sending multiple sets of data to the template?**

I'd really appreciate any sort of answers that could lead me in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd advice the second option. Probably easiest way, that plays nicely with reactivity, is as follow.

Suppose you've got a blog with `Articles`, `Comments` and `Meteor.users` collections, related in a predictable way - that is a `comment` has `articleId` and `userId` fields. Let also `article` and `comment` have both a `content` field. You can display it with the following template:

```
<template name="article">
    {{#with article}}
        {{content}}
        {{#each comments}}
            {{content}} - {{username}}
        {{/each}}
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Now, you get the data as follows:

```
Template.article.article = function() {
    return Articles.findOne(...articleId...);
};

Template.article.comments = function() {
    return Comments.find({articleId: this._id});
};

Template.article.username = function() {
    var user = Meteor.users.find(this.userId);
    return user ? user.username : '';
};
```

Comment: So, to loosely adapt your blog example, what would you do if you needed to display multiple articles and their comments on a page? Would you just multiple iterations of the same article? How would you pass the ID?

Comment: In the template, replace `#with` with `#each`. In `article` helper, replace `findOne(articleId)` with `find({_id: {$in: [id1, id2, id3]}})`.